# Cloth doesn't bend enough on sharp edges

Tags: physics

I have a cloth sitting on a table. The problem I have is the cloth edge should be nearly as sharp as the table edge, but it's not, it's way too smooth. What is causing this?

[image]

Mesh and modifiers:

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload screen shot of your modifiers and edit mode of your cloth

Comment: @BlenderForYou Done!

Comment: Please try the solution below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please move the **Cloth modifier** under the **Subdivision surface** modifier

as shown below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked really well. However now the cloth starts glitching and include artifacts so I had to increase the subsurf samples and the simulation quality, and now it takes forever to render. Guess I have to live with it.

Comment: ok, I am glad it worked for you,Please accept the answer to correct

Comment: Re render issue, duplicate the object and hide it for future use, than you may drop the cloth once, stop the animation where do you see the cloth fits, apply they modifiers one by one in order, let me know if it worked for you

Comment: Oh, so I can apply a subsurf after it's simulated? Do I lose quality if I do it after?

Comment: yes, apply subsurface and cloth too, so it will sit on table on which frame you applied. it will not lose quality

Comment: And in future if you are looking for edit or something, you may use the duplicated created above, edit it, simulate it again, apply the modifiers and enjoy :)